# Electron notification "show" method not working during Microsoft teams meeting screen sharing session

Tags: windows, notifications, electron, microsoft-teams, screensharing

Electron notification "show" method not working during Microsoft teams screen sharing. I am using windows machine and electron-forge package for packaging the application. Notifications are working correctly if screen sharing is not ON and MS teams meeting is joined. Issue is only during screen sharing using MS teams application on windows.

I am trying to show notification from Electron main process as per documentation given here:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/notification
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/notifications#show-notifications-in-the-main-process

It works perfectly while running in local and with packaged application using electron-forge.
But As soon as I start MS Teams meeting and try to share the screen, the same notification is not showing up. I have already set AppUserModelID in main process. I have put the code in try catch block but it is not throwing up any error. It is just moving on to next lines of code. Below code is not the complete but it has all the relevant details.

const { app, BrowserWindow, Notification } = require('electron')

const NOTIFICATION_TITLE = "Test1";
const NOTIFICATION_BODY = "test2";

```
    const notification = new Notification({
        title: NOTIFICATION_TITLE, body: NOTIFICATION_BODY,
        silent: false,           
        urgency: 'critical',
    });

    notification.show();
```

app.on('ready', () => app.setAppUserModelId("Test GUI"));

Somehow the MS teams app is messing up with electron notification. This issue is happening on Windows machine.

Expected behavior: Electron notifications should be shown irrespective of screen sharing using MS Teams application.